# Migration issue - Kodo/OpenJPA to EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, openjpa

I have an environment setup with Java EE (weblogic 10.0). Thus, Kodo/OpenJPA is used as the JPA implementation. For some reasons I want to migrate to EclipseLink. 
Now I have the following issue:

1. Entity A -- ManyToMany -- Entity B
2. FetchType.Lazy, Cascade{}
3. JoinTable AxB
4. ForeignKey Constraint AxB.FK_COL -> A.PK

If I want to remove the Entity A, the entry in the join column should also be deleted

Kodo/OpenJPA -> Deletion successful, SQL Trace shows, that first the AxB rows are deleted

EclipseLink -> Deletion fails, Foreign Key Constraint violation. EL tries to delete Entity A first.

This is all in one transaction (RESOURCE_LOCAL). My thought was, that if something is within a transaction, foreign key constraints may be violated? Can the order of the deletions be changed in a way that first the Join Table rows are deleted?

I use EclipseLink 1.1.4

Thanks for your help,
Soccertrash

Comment: This seems to be a bug fixed in 2.1
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in later versions of EclipseLink.  Try 2.0, or the latest 2.3.

Otherwise remove the target object from the collection first and call flush.